# Linux freezes shut when cursor touches bottom of the screen

Tags: xfce, freeze, openbox, lxqt

Linux freezes shut when cursor touches bottom of the screen, stops responding to anything, happens in LXQT, Openbox and XFCE, tried different distros. Is there any fix to this problem? Specs are: Intel Atom N2100 CPU, Intel GMA 3600 iGPU, 4GB DDR3 1600 MHz RAM.

Comment: Now, *that* is a strange problem.

Comment: Sounds like hardware or driver issues. Try a different Linux distribution or one of the BSD distributions to see if it also happens.